# How to send form-data in Ruby http post

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'd like to send a post from my Rails app to an API. I can get this to work using POSTMAN:

[image: postman screenshot]

If I click on Preview in POSTMAN, it shows this as the request:

```
POST /api/users/status HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params"

{"pgb": "sample_token", "token": "sample_token" }
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Which is what I want to send. But I can't seem to replicate form-data when using Ruby's Net::HTTP::Post. Here's what I have so far, but this posts with x-www-form-urlencoded as the content-type:

```
url = URI.parse(ENV['URL'])

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.set_form_data({"params" => data.to_json})

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
https.set_debug_output $stdout

resp = https.request(req)
response = JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

Is there any way to post just form-data with ruby?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using some of Ruby gems like Rest client.  http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client

Just type the following

```
gem install rest-client
```

The documentation can be found here http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client.